# Slickgrid - how to get the value of edited cells?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I'd like to make my code be able to update database table immediately when the cell is changed. However, I can get the value of the changed cell whereas not the data of those of next cell.

Methods I have tried already without success:

```
grid.onCellChange.subscribe(
    function (e, args) {
        //alert(data[args.row][grid.getColumns()[args.cell].field]);
        //alert(grid.getColumns()[args.cell].name);
        //alert(args);
        <%
            updateDatabase("UPDATE table1 "+
                           "SET "+
                           "  col1="+data[args.row][grid.getColumns()[args.cell].field]+" "+
                           "WHERE "+
                           "  col2="+???)") 
        %>
    }
);
```

How to get the value of the next column that I can use in the `where` clause ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Addressing your problem:**

If you check out the official [SlickGrid Editing](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example3-editing.html) demo, you can try the following to get a basic understanding how grid editing works. Open your JS debugger and subscribe to the grids `onCellChange` event using the following command:

```
grid.onCellChange.subscribe(
    function (e,args) {
        console.log('row: ' + args.row + ' cell: ' + args.cell)
    });
```

The grid's `onCellChange` events `args` argument object contains two properties:

- *row*
- *cell*

Now edit any of the cells and *leave* the just edited cell. It's important since this event will only fire on *blur* event.

In the console log you will see for instance:

> row: 6 cell: 1

**Addressing your data object**:

The only way I found how could you *address* your data source is in a  **hackish** way only using [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). For further information about object property accessing you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866275/access-non-numeric-object-properties-by-index) answer.

---

**A bit from the Javascript jargon:**

The actual [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) command to address your data object with the given *fieldname* or *property name* is:

```
eval('data[args.row]'+'.'+columns[args.cell].field)
```

Simplified it will *evaluate the JavaScript code represented as a string*, in this [SlickGrid Editing example](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example3-editing.html) it will become as if you would write:

```
data[6].title
```

---

So the proof of concept code is:

```
grid.onCellChange.subscribe(
    function (e,args) {
        console.log(eval('data[args.row]'+'.'+columns[args.cell].field))
    });
```

This will return you the value of the current edited cell. For instance changing `args.cell+1` will return you the next cell value from the data source of your grid. Of course you should always check the `columns.length` property to keep the column index key inside of array bounds.

---

**Regarding your idea about the `updateDatabase` call:** why do you want to update the database after every time this event gets fired? I suggest you to take a look at the official [Composite editor](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-composite-editor-item-details.html) demo which has an edit form.

The other thing I would strongly advise is that you **not** write *server side* or *code behind* code directly into the *javascript* code block. For example, you could make it use an [*ajax post*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274796/passing-multiple-parameters-using-ajax-by-post-to-php-function).

The reason I recommend this is because then you are going to have separated functions with *separated* [responsibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711851/writing-javascript-according-to-solid). Just by adhering to this principle in itself could lead you to have a cleaner code, also you only give one reason to change. Also it may help [testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/javascript-unit-test-tools-for-tdd) your functions much easier.